# BATCH FILE BUG IF STRING == STRING

Tags: batch-file

I do not know how to go to check.
This is a script to list the files with the extension .pbo contained in the record and move them to a third party software to their applied a safety signature

```
for %%a in (*.pbo) do (
    echo %%a
    %TOOLSPATH%%app2% %key% %%a

    :: DOES NOT WORK, WHY ?
    :: DOES NOT WORK, WHY ?
    :: DOES NOT WORK, WHY ?
    IF %%a==Wrong private key file echo Error please restart tools
)
```

MY FULL CODE

```
 @echo off
    :: Defini le chemin du dossier sur la machine
    SET TOOLSPATH=%~dp0

    :: Defini les 2 fichiers nécéssaire à la création des signatures
    SET app1=bin\DSCreateKey.exe
    SET app2=bin\DSSignFile.exe
    SET key=test.biprivatekey
    SET corrompu=Votre logiciel est corrompu, merci de prendre contact avec @Flolax

    IF NOT EXIST %TOOLSPATH%%app1% (
        echo -----------ERREUR-----------
        echo %TOOLSPATH%%app1% est introuvable
        echo.

        echo %corrompu%
    )

    IF NOT EXIST %TOOLSPATH%%app2% (
        echo -----------ERREUR-----------
        echo %TOOLSPATH%%app1% est introuvable
        echo.

        echo %corrompu%
    )

    cd %TOOLSPATH%\addons

    for %%a in (*.pbo) do (
        echo %%a
        %TOOLSPATH%%app2% %key% %%a

        IF %%a==Wrong private key file echo erreur
    )

    pause
```

AND SCREEN

http://prntscr.com/5e2fhi

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in (*.pbo) do (
    echo %%a
    %TOOLSPATH%%app2% %key% %%a

    IF "%%a"=="Wrong private key file" echo erreur
```

batch needs to know whuch elements to group. `"quoting a space-separated string"` groups the phrase into one item.

**BUT**

`%%a` here will be the name of a `*.pbo` file, so it would never match that string.

---

As I said, `%%a` here will be the name of a `*.pbo` file, so it would never match that string, which you should have been able to determine wince it is being `echo`ed. The value of `%%a` will never match `Wrong private key file`

To assign the output of your command to a variable (in this case the metavariable `%%r`) use

```
for /f "delims=" %%r in ('%TOOLSPATH%%app2% %key% %%a') do IF "%%r"=="Wrong private key file" echo erreur
```

- but that doesn't answer your question which was about matching two strings. First, you need to assign the strings correctly.

And since we've no indication of the output of of identity of `app2` then it's not possible to be certain that this code will work either. Need more information.

Oh - and please delete your "answer" as it's not an answer but a comment.

---

Ah - it's unusual for an application to produce a message to `stderr` even if it's logically correct. Try this...

```
for /f "delims=" %%r in ('%TOOLSPATH%%app2% %key% %%a 2^>^&1') do IF "%%r"=="Wrong private key file" echo erreur
```

The `2^>^&1` gymnastics redirects the `stderr` output to `stdout`. `cmd` requires the carets `^` to escape the special characters `>` and `&` within the paentheses of a `for /f` command.

Comment: Hi magoo, thanks for reply.

Your script does not work

Comment: Thanks you for your help, unfortunately it does not work
http://prntscr.com/5f4gxp